# php - print even and (sorted) odd numbers of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array given below

```
$array = array(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59);
```

I am trying to print the values of array while even numbers will remain in same order and the odd numbers are sorted i.e. 59,57,55,53,51

The output should be like

```
50,59,52,57,54,55,56,53,58,51
```

I've separated the even and odd numbers in two diff variables. how should i proceed further ?

here is my code

```
  $even= "";
  $odd= "";

for($i=50;$i<=59;$i++)
{
    if($i%2==0)
    {
        $even.=$i.",";
    }else $odd.=$i.","; 
}   
echo $even.$odd;
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: i've edited my post #Jay

Comment: you want to sort  based on number or based on index?

Comment: sort only odd numbers, from 59-57-55-53-51 #Yasin

Comment: Something like this should work for you: https://3v4l.org/MRu43 basically you get the odd values out of the array and sort them. After that you just replace the odd values from your original array with the sorted odd values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of pushing the evens and odds into a string, push them each into an array, sort the array with the odds in reverse and then loop through one of them (preferably through the even array) and add the even and the odd to a new array.

This is how I've done it:

```
$array = array(50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59);
$odds = array();
$even = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
    if($val % 2 == 0) {
        $even[] = $val;
    } else {
        $odds[] = $val;
    }
}

sort($even);
rsort($odds);

$array = array();
foreach($even as $key => $val) {
    $array[] = $val;
    if(isset($odds[$key])) {
        $array[] = $odds[$key];
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/2hW6T

But you should be cautious if you have less even than odd numbers, as the loop will finish before all odds are added. You can check for that either before or after you've filled the new array. If you check after filling the new array, you can use `array_diff` and `array_merge` to add the missing odds to the new array.

http://php.net/array_diff http://php.net/array_merge

Comment: This will only work as long as odd and even values are in alternating order.

Comment: @Rizier123 Why should it only work if they're in alternating order?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois For example if there are two odd or even values besides each other in the array it will break: https://3v4l.org/lN4aj

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't see anything broken. It's in the intended order.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will run as per the odd number count. There won't be any loop count issue.

```
  function oddNumber($num){
    return $num % 2 == 1;
  }

  $givenArray = array(50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59);

  $oddArray = array_filter($givenArray, "oddNumber");

  rsort($oddArray);

  $finalArray = array();
  $oddCount = 0;
  foreach($givenArray as $num){
      if(oddNumber($num)){    
          $finalArray[] = $oddArray[$oddCount];
          ++$oddCount;
      }else{
          $finalArray[] = $num;    
      }
  }

  print_r($finalArray);
```