# How to print all even numbers between two input values typed by user. please write code hint only in php

Tags: php

How to print all even numbers between two input values typed by user. please write code hint only in php.

Comment: SO is not the place ask for coding.

Comment: show us your best effort first. How much you tried so far ?

Comment: just tell me hints only dont write all code

Comment: NO! At first, try on your own and show us if you get any issue

Comment: 5 to 10 times but not succeed. @fahim152

Comment: this might help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085697/php-print-even-and-sorted-odd-numbers-of-an-array. If you tried something and are still stuck, then ask a new question and add the code you have so far.

Comment: show us the code u tried first, edit your question

Comment: This question can help you understanding how to find if your number is odd or even : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175947/odd-and-even-numbers-using-or

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this code, for user input i have created a form.

```
   <html>  
    <body>  
    <form method="post"> 
        <input type="number" name="num1">  
        <input type="number" name="num2"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>  
    </body>  
    </html> 
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
        $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
        //  while loop that will print number
        while($num1 <= $num2){
            //  here is the condition to check the EVEN number
            if($num1%2!==0){
                echo $num1."<br>";
                }
                // increasing the loope counter by 1
            $num1++;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

i hope now your problem has been solved..

Comment: use this code to print all even number between two input,

Comment: Thank You Buddy for this by while loop. i tried it by for loop but not succeed. @MUFAzmi

Comment: @ROHIBOSS welcome buddy.
Please accept my answer by clicking the check if this helped you.

Comment: Great Job....Checked. @MUFAzmi

Comment: Why For Loop Is not Working For this? can you tell me suggestion?

Comment: it will also work bro with the for loop...

Comment: let me send the code, which will i done it by using for loop...

Comment: ok waiting for your code...............!

Comment: oops, stackiverflow.com is not allowing more than 99 words in comment section, so i can't post the code here..

Comment: you can ask another question. and mention their to use for loop only.

Comment: ok sure but stackoverflow blocked me for 3 days. i dont know the rules of asking on stackoverflow!

Comment: Hello sir, now you can ask a question, that how can fetch the even number using for loop...

Comment: But remember, you have to post what you have tried.. mention that code, and say that i have tried it using while loop and now i want same output from using for loop

Comment: And please share your questions link here, i have done this also with the while loop, so i will post my answer there..

Comment: Sorry, not only while, but also using for loop also

Comment: ok i already asked new question please try that @MUFAzmi

Comment: try my new question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027248?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a hint. Lookup the [modulo operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). With it you can do something like this:

```
<?php
    if (($number % 2) === 1)
      {
          echo "$number is odd.";
      }
      if (($number % 2) === 0)
      { 
          echo "$number is even." ;
      }
?>
```

Also. Have a look at how you ask questions on stack overflow. Or they will prevent you from asking questions in the future if you don't adhere to those rules.