# how to select a value from dropdown then click on submit and then print value in same page in div section further div also working with button?

Tags: php

how to select a value from dropdown then click on submit and then print value in same page in div section and then div work well with further required button codings?

i have tried for alert but not succeed i want print full detail description of dropdown selection value on same page. and further button on that printed description work as well.

```
<?php 
function checkdropdown() {
      if(document.getElementById('select').value != "") {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
?>

<form action='file.php' action='post'>
      <select name='select' id='select'>
        <option value=''>Select an option</option>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5</option>
        <option value='6'>6</option>
        <option value='7'>7</option>
        <option value='8'>8</option>
      </select>
    <input type='submit' onClick='if(!checkdropdown()) {alert("You need to select a value!"); return false;}' value='Submit form' />
    </form>
```

Comment: its just sample code............I want this in post submission php then print description of dropdown selected value

Comment: no one here to solve this question?

Comment: what you exactly want to do here?

Comment: are you want to print the value when user select any option..

Comment: **you are sending data to the another page.**
When user back from that page, then you want to print their selected value..
am i right?

Comment: i want to print description of that value not that value name......... means if my dropdown value is vegetable then long description of the vegetable put in bottom of dropdown menu on same page and also next working buttons or links in that vegetable description works further results. Please give me hint in php only

Answer (score 0):

Please check below.

```
<div id="divtouse"> This is the Div to place html </div>
<form action='file.php' action='post'>
    <select name='select' id='select'>
        <option value=''>Select an option</option>
        <option value='1' data-desc="long description 1">1</option>
        <option value='2' data-desc="long description 2">2</option>
        <option value='3' data-desc="long description 3">3</option>
        <option value='4' data-desc="long description 4">4</option>
        <option value='5' data-desc="long description 5">5</option>
        <option value='6' data-desc="long description 6">6</option>
        <option value='7' data-desc="long description 7">7</option>
        <option value='8' data-desc="long description 8">8</option>
    </select>
    <input 
        type='submit'
        onClick='if(!checkdropdown()) {
            alert("You need to select a value!"); return false;
        }'
        value='Submit form' 
    />
</form>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function checkdropdown() {
    if(document.getElementById('select').value != "") {
        var selectval = document.getElementById('select').value;

        var sel = document.getElementById('select');
        var selected = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
        var long_description= selected.getAttribute('data-desc');


        var htmldiv = '<p>'+long_description+'</p><input type="button" value="Vlick Button" onclick="divbtnsubmit('+selectval+')" />';
        document.getElementById('divtouse').innerHTML = htmldiv;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function divbtnsubmit(selectedvalue) {
    //you can do button functionality in the div stuffs here.
}
```

Comment: @ROHIBOSS Can you describe why you are not satisfied?

Comment: @Bhupati can you add more description to your solution?

Comment: @Colin not satisfied..because i said description of that value means if my dropdown value is vegetable then long description of the vegetable put in bottom of dropdown menu on same page and also next working buttons or links in that vegetable description works further results

Comment: i want one dropdown menu and one submit button. and when i select one value and then press submit button then on same page, shows description of that value not value name....and also want further working in that description section means buttons links present in that description works well............... PHP only

Comment: @Rohiboss from where you are going to show long description if you select value any value(vegetable) from the dropdown. Request you to show your demo url if possible.

Comment: @BhupatiJagi dont know coding for that i written. thats why i am asking here......if you r web developer then show your potential otherwise no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code :

```
<div id="divtouse">This is the value which you have selected:-  </div>

    <form >
          <select name='select' id='select'>
            <option value=''>Select an option</option>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
          </select>
        <input type='submit'  onClick='if(!checkdropdown()) {alert("You need to select a value!"); return false;}' value='Submit form' />
    </form>
```

Javascript Code

```
<script>
        function checkdropdown() {
        if(document.getElementById('select').value != "") {
                return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        }
        var select = document.getElementById('select');
        select.onchange = function() 
        {
            document.getElementById("divtouse").textContent="This is the value which you have selected:- "+select.value;
        }
</script>
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: not satisfied... i said description of that value means if my dropdown value is vegetable then long description of the vegetable put in bottom of  dropdown menu 
 on same page and also next working buttons or links in that vegetable description works further results.